# Shuffled result in ORM query

Tags: php, orm, kohana

Let say that I have a table of some data. I want am running a query using ORM in Kohana 2.3.

```
ORM::factory('somemodel')->find_all(); // ordered by $sort
```

I want to modify that query to return shuffled results.

Comment: By 'shuffled' do you mean sorted by some columns, or ordered randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rand.

Here is the example for it

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder#orderby